# Tipo Int8 no Swift não armazena o máximo inteiro 255

Tags: swift, objective-c, tipagem

Fazendo algumas brincadeiras no Playground, Com Swift 2.2 podemos declarar constantes

```
let testeIntOitoBits: Int8 = 127 //maximo - deveria ser 255
let testeIntOitoBits2: UInt8 = 255
```

Por que não posso armazenar 255 no tipo Int8 e no tipo UInt8 sim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar isto para descobrir o valor máximo de um tipo:

```
print(Int8.max) //vai responder 127
print(UInt8.max) //vai responder 255
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Limit.swift).

`Int8` é um tipo inteiro sinalizado, ou seja, ele tem 8 bits e um deles é o sinal se o número é positivo ou negativo. Sobra apenas 7 bits pra representar o número mesmo. Com 7 bits só podemos representar 128 números diferentes, portanto só pode ir de 0 à 127. No caso dos negativos como não precisa representar o 0, vai de -1 à -128. Totalizando 256 números diferentes (-128 à 127). Se mandar pegar o `Int8.min` receberá um -128.

Já o `UInt8` é um inteiro não sinalizado (o `U` significa *unsigned*) e pode usar os 8 bits pra representar o número, portanto dá para representar de 0 à 255. Obviamente não pode representar números negativos.

Evite usar tipos não sinalizados. Use só onde for realmente necessário e quando entenda todas implicações do seu. Reforço esta recomendação: é raro ser útil usar um tipo não sinalizado. Você vai achar que precisa dele, mas provavelmente será um decisão errada. Quando tiver certeza que precisa certifique-se que já entendeu todas diferenças de trabalhar com aritmética em um tipo assim.

Comment: muito esclarecedor! Obrigadíssimo!